# Pymatgen: How to convert query result to structure

Tags: python, pymatgen

We have existing code to get some material properties for many materials (>60,000).

```
from pymatgen import MPRester
mpr = MPRester(api_key="")
criteria={"nelements":{'$lt':4}}
properties=["pretty_formula","cif","material_id", "formation_energy_per_atom", "band_gap"]

c = mpr.query(criteria=criteria,properties=properties)
```

But for this project we need the information in a specific form, namely in structures. I can get this structures easily by calling them for every material ID individually:

```
structures = []
for mid in mid_list:
    structures.append(mpr.get_structure_by_material_id(mid))
```

Which calls this function in matproj.py:

```
    def get_structure_by_material_id(self, material_id, final=True,
                                     conventional_unit_cell=False):
        """
        Get a Structure corresponding to a material_id.

        Args:
            material_id (str): Materials Project material_id (a string,
                e.g., mp-1234).
            final (bool): Whether to get the final structure, or the initial
                (pre-relaxation) structure. Defaults to True.
            conventional_unit_cell (bool): Whether to get the standard
                conventional unit cell

        Returns:
            Structure object.
        """
```

The problem is, that this takes very long (>4 hours) and sometimes gets stuck during the call to the API.

Is there a way to avoid calling the API 60,000 times and convert the initial query results instead?

Comment: Where is structure defined?

Comment: I see what you mean, structures is just an empty list that gets filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to query for each individual mpid. Your first code block already queries for the `"cif"` information of all the materials!

All you need to do is to convert the cif strings to structures using PyMatGen:

```
from pymatgen.io.cif import CifParser
structures = []
for material in c:
    structures.append(CifParser.from_string(material["cif"]).get_structures()[0])
```